# Passing Middleman FrontMatter variables into Helper Tags

Tags: ruby, middleman

I want to pass some YAML FrontMatter from a page via something like this:

`<%= image_tag 'current_page.data.image_path' %>`

I know that doesn't work because it's treating it as a plain old string rather than a variable, but I'm new to Ruby and Middleman so I'm not sure the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the quotes:

```
<%= image_tag current_page.data.image_path %>
```